# List view localization in Managed Package

Tags: managed-package, list-view, localization

I know that's a very long story about localization support for list views and report, discussed for example [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br0P). But for end users there is a workaround: create the same list views with localized languages, create public groups for users with different languages and assign list views to these groups.
Does anyone know if there is there any workaround for ISVs? I mean, is there a way to localize list view in managed package?